# Validate only one field ng-required angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-validation

How to validate only one field in form with different button-click rather that submit button?

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" ng-model="vm.foo" ng-required="true"></textarea>

<button type="button" ng-click="vm.CheckValid()">Check Valid</button>

vm.CheckValid=function(){
   //How to trigger ng-required instead? 
   if (vm.foo!="") {
     //do stuffs
   }
   else return false;
}
```

Comment: So what is not working?

Comment: I want to add **This field is required** below the textarea if it is null in Check Valid click. Right now it returns false if its null but I need to show user why is it returning null.